# How to run React application and Express server automatically on hosting site

Tags: reactjs, express, server, stripe-payments, web-hosting

I apologize if this question exists in some form, I've been searching and searching, but couldn't find the solution.

I'm new to web development but I don't think my problem is too complex. Basically, I'm trying to run a react application that charges a user (through Stripe) and confirms it with an Express backend server. To run this locally, I start the React app with npm start and in a separate command line window, run node server.js.

Everything is perfect and functional locally, however fails when I upload to my website. How can I start the backend server at start to run alongside the React application?

I've tried running the script in the index.html, but I ran into problems with it giving errors (uncaught syntax error) which from what I've searched is just an effect of trying to run code on browser as opposed to through all of my react/webpack settings.

I apologize, but I'm not sure what code is relevant to the problem

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) which got everything working locally, but expanding to production is not working

Comment: You *don't* run them both remotely; most setups can only expose one port anyway, and the React dev server isn't suitable for production use. Instead you build the app and serve it from Express; see e.g. this project I put together https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should've specified. I build the application with npm run build and upload the files to the hosting site. I'm wondering how exactly I would go about running both the app and the backend on the site

Comment: You don't. You can either have one static server and one Node server, or get the Node server to also serve the static files. The project I linked does the latter.